# push file onto android emulator and pull a file from the emulator programmatically

Tags: android, android-emulator

I need a piece of code that helps me to store data from my computer onto android emulator (for example I want to store the "C/Users/Desktop/myFile.txt" onto my emulator sd card) and  vice-versa (store file from sd card onto my computer) programmatically (because i know how to do it manually !!!!)
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use the Adroid debug bridge (`adb`) to push and pull files to and from your device or emulator: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#copyfiles

If you want to automate this, you can use a shell script.

Comment: thnx for your answer. can you explain how can i use the script, how to write it ?

Comment: If you just want to copy a single file, you don't need to write a script. I would only do it if there are a lot of copy operations.